# Socket I/O mode epoll,overlapped I/O

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I am working client server application where I need to manage multiple socket connection 1000+.

By exploration I found out the Overlapped I/O or Completion Port is nice to do de-multiplexing multiple socket in Windows and epoll is nice on Linux.

1. Is epoll is different from Overlapped I/O or Completion Port in windows.
2. I wanted to use boost since it works on both windows and Linux.

Is it possible to implement these techniques (epoll and Overlapped I/O or Completion Port) using boost?

Comment: Do boost internally implement these I/O technique and these things are part of asynchronous I/O.Please correct my finding.So if one does asynchronous I/O internally it takes appropriate I/O technique is it???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of `epoll` on Linux and I/O completion ports on Windows are different, however Boost.Asio nicely abstracts away the differences for your application. This is the whole point of the `io_service` [reactor queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html):

**Windows NT, 2000, XP, 2003 and Vista**

Demultiplexing mechanism:

- Uses overlapped I/O and I/O
  completion ports for all asynchronous
  socket operations except for
  asynchronous connect.
- Uses select for emulating asynchronous connect.

**Linux Kernel 2.6**

Demultiplexing mechanism:

- Uses epoll for demultiplexing.